# Cannot remove white space below Carousel Bootstrap and Social Media icon in Mobile Version

Tags: html, css, carousel, space

This is my website when viewed in PC:

[image]

While I was inspecting the mobile-version, I realized there is a huge gap between the car image and the bottom social media icons. As a matter of fact, there is another huge space below the social media icons.

This is what I see in mobile version (there is a social media icon at the very bottom but is not shown due to the spacing):

So far, I have tried adjusting the .carousel-inner img to max-height and max-width: 100%. Also tried creating .carousel-item as height: ___px, but it won't seem to work properly.

Basically, I want the blank spaces to be removed so the website looks much nicer in mobile version.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="monday.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>J[a]son</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class = "logo">
            <h4>J[a]son</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class = "nav-links">
            <li>
                <a href="#">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="photography_colour.html">Colour</a></li>
                    <li><a href="photography_black.html">Black</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">CODING</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class= "burger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="testing.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">-->
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-75" src="Photos/carousel.JPG" alt="First slide">
            <p>November, 2019. Seattle, USA.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-75" src="Photos/statute.JPG" alt="Second slide">
            <p>June, 2020. Kelowna, BC.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
           <!--<p>June, 2020. Sunshine Coast, BC, Canada </p>-->
    <div class ="bottom">
      <div class = "logos">
        <a href="https://github.com/j-ahn94" target="_blank" class="fa fa-github"></a>
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/14266888/jason-a" target="_blank" class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jasonja-ahn/" target="_blank" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: black !important; /*rgb(241, 233, 233);*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    
}

nav {
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /*padding-right: 2em;*/
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 1.5em;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: black;
    /*font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;*/
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.logo {
    background-color: black;
    color: rgb(240, 235, 235);
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 30%;
}

.nav-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    /*padding: 5px 5px;*/
}

.burger {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1430px) {
    .nav-links {
        width: 40%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:950px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background-color: black;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 45%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        padding-right: 2em;
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    .nav-links li {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .burger {
        display: block;
        padding-right: 1em;
    }
    .sub-menu {
        position: relative;
    }
}

.nav-active {
    transform: translate(0%);https://ahweb.org.uk/car.png
}

.main_car_wrapper {
    background-image: url(https://ahweb.org.uk/car.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 6em;
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }
    to {
        opacity :1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}

.toggle .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.toggle .line2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);

}

.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}

.sub-menu li a {
    /*display: block;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    background: rgb(221, 215, 215);
    white-space: nowrap;
    top: 40px;
    left: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 1px;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover{
    background: rgb(10, 10, 10);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;   
}

li:hover ul {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
}

li:hover li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 8px;
}

li:hover a {
    background: rgb(5, 5, 5);
}

li:hover li a:hover {
    background: rgb(19, 18, 18);
}

.bottom {
    margin-top: auto; 
}

.logos {
    display: flex !important;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: black;
}

.logos a {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.carousel-inner p {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.carousel-inner {
    background-color: black;
}

.carousel-inner img {
    /*display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 60vw;
    max-height: auto;
    align-items: center;*/
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.carousel-item {
    height: 300px;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

JavaScript

```
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
  //Toggle Nav
  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //Toggle Nav
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

    //Animate Links
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if(link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = ''
      } else {
          link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.2s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s`;
      }
    });
    //Burger Animation
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
  });
  //Animate Links
  
}

navSlide();
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those icons are located within

```
    <div class ="bottom">
      <div class = "logos">
              Logos Are Here
      </div>
    </div>
```

Therefore if you check those classes in CSS you will find:

```
.bottom {
    margin-top: auto; 
}
```

and

```
.logos {
    display: flex !important;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: black;
}
```

By simply changing margin-top from auto to the perspective percentage you can fix this issue:

```
.bottom {
        margin-top: 1%; 
    }
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Hello. I have added my code here: https://codepen.io/ajs20555/pen/JjRYmpd

Comment: Hello. Thank you so much for helping out. So simply put, I want the social media logos at the very bottom. My issue is that there is a blank space below the logos when I inspect the webpage in mobile version.

Comment: That would be because of the dimensions of that image

Comment: Image as in carousel image or the social media icons..? When I toggle the bottom section in Inspect, I can’t hover anything..

Comment: The dimension of the image in the gallery. “Auto” is going to keep the icons floating at the bottom of the screen. If that is where you want them, if you have a horizontal dimensioned image above, there will be a giant space. 

That is unless you want to change the image viewframe on mobile. In this case it will cut off a large section of the image however and be a “zoomed in” display

Comment: Now that I reread this I think I understand more what you are talking about. You mean the black space that is prevalent underneath the logos? Let me look into this for you

Comment: I was confused because the issue you are referencing does not exist in the CodePen

Comment: Thank you so so much!!

Comment: Yes because i can only see the blank space at the very bottom in mobile, while viewing it through PC looks fine..

Comment: When viewing mobile in CodePen I do not see the issue

Comment: Shoot. Thank you for the help tho!